# Replacing socket underlying URL connection in Java

Tags: java, sockets, url, tunnel, network-interface

I have a Java application that uses `java.net.URL` to open a location to retrieve some data. I now have the requirement to open the connection via VPN. The Linux machine it runs on, now can have a number of tunnels open at any one time, and I need to be able to programmatically tell the application which tunnel to use.

I believe that using `java.net.Socket` it's possible to choose the virtual device to open the connection on, but I could not find any way to overlay the URL object to handle all the HTTP traffic - or replace the underlying socket before actually opening the connection.

So, how do I connect my application to a particular network interface and keep the advantage of using a high-level object like `java.net.URL`?

Now, I am not sure if this is possible at all, but I thought I'd ask the wise stackoverflow community...

Comment: An application typically doesn't have to do anything special to use a VPN connection. The routing table of the operating system has to be set up correctly though. So, what's the question/problem?

Comment: Hi Joni, the question is: how do I tell my application which tunnel to use between tun0-00, tun1-00, etc. as opposed to the default network interface? It's important because the tunnels come out at different locations and I need to choose where to send my traffic.

Comment: You configure that in the routing table of the operating system: "send traffic to these IP addresses via this interface" Does your VPN not set up the routes correctly? Which VPN do you use? Which OS do you use?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to force my application to use a particular tunnel only if it goes to a particular address (an address beyond the gateway at the other end, that is). There can actually be multiple instances of the same application running at any one time, each one possibly getting to the same destination but using a different tunnel. I'm using OpenVPN on CentOS - don't ask...

Comment: To make that work you need different IP address ranges for the destination. If you configure two network interfaces in the same network the OS can't guarantee which one it uses. So, you would need to add a NAT layer somewhere, or think of a different solution...

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can register a custom `URLStreamHandlerFactory` with `java.net.URL`. Whenever `openConnection()` is called on the URL it would be handled by this registered custom factory, giving you control over details of the socket connection.

Once you have the ability to manipulate socket creation, specifying the network interface you use is fairly trivial:

```
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0");
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.bind(ni.getInetAddresses().nextElement());
```

It looks like there are a few libraries out there that provide simple access for setting the socketFactory used by an HTTP connection. See for example http://faban.org/1.1/docs/api/index.html?com/sun/faban/driver/transport/sunhttp/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: That sounds very interesting. Investigating further it seems that something similar is possible with the Apache HTTP client as shown on [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java) example. I suppose one can create a socket like you suggest  and use the client's Connection Manager to register it.

Comment: While this does bind the socket's local address to the IP of a particular network interface, the OS can use any of the other interfaces in the same network to send the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom SocketImplFactory and then set it as default using Socket.setSocketImplFactory, but I am not sure how you can select a network interface on the client side, that would be the function of the routing.